# Mysql, trigger update affect multiple row of the same table

Tags: mysql

I need some help for the following prob:

I have a table "item" with 3 columns [name|description|panel] as follow:

```
|---name---|---description---|---panel---|
|----------|-----------------|-----------|
|name1     | this is a glass |  name4    |
|name2     | this is a plate |  name4    |
|name3     | this is a fork  |  name4    |
|name4     | this is a panel |  name4    |
|name5     | this is a spoon |  name4    |
|name6     | this is a glass |  name9    |
|name7     | this is a plate |  name9    |
|name8     | this is a fork  |  name9    |
|name9     | this is a panel |  name9    |
|name10    | this is a spoon |  name9    |
```

This table contains some item and there storage location is define as a panel. but the panel itself is an item.

What I want is: if I update name4 in name column, it is updated in panel column too where panel = name4.

I tried many solution before/after triggers, using a stored procedure. But always the same error "Can't update table 'item' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger." and I understand it ...

But is there any walk around ?

My code is as follow :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`remote_root`@`%` TRIGGER `db`.`U_item` AFTER UPDATE ON `item` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.name<> OLD.name)
    THEN  
     UPDATE item
      SET
      panel= NEW.name
      Where (panel=OLD.name);

    END IF;
END
```

Comment: In MySQL a trigger cannot act on the table which caused it to fire (otherwise you'd get a potentially infinite recursion).  So you'll have to rethink your logic.

Comment: Use 2 tables and id's to achieve this

Comment: Well I understand that the mechanism protects against infinite recursion but for a simple trigger as this one it a pitty that we have no choice but create another table ... Thanks guys

Comment: You must use stored procedures. Function/Trigger cannot do this. You probably need to remove any self referencing& cascading relationship.